# Less complicated concatenation in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, concatenation, separator

I have multiple str-variables and I want to concatenate them to single line but with separator:

```
var_a + 'SEPARATOR' + var_b + 'SEPARATOR' + var_c + 'SEPARATOR' + var_d
```

As you can see, it looks disgusting and unefficient.

So, is there any way to make it simpler by adding separator automatically between separate strings?

P.S.
I like the way it works in print function:

```
print(var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, sep="SEPARATOR")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join()` function:

```
    words = [var_a,var_b,var_c,var_d]
    my_separator = "this is a separator"
    my_expected_sentence= my_separator.join(words)
```

Update:
Also you can use your custom method:

```
def my_join(args, sep):
  sentence=""
  for i in args:
      sentence+=i+sep
  return sentence

words=["abc","def","ghi"]
data = my_join(words,'hello')
print(data)
```

In this way you can add separator before every words.Like:

```
def my_preceding_join(args, sep):
      sentence=""
      for i in args:
          sentence+=sep+i
      return sentence

    data = my_preceding_join(words,'hello')
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.join`:

```
def custom_join(*args, sep=''):
  return sep.join(args)

print(custom_join('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', sep="SEPARATOR"))
```

Output:

```
aSEPARATORbSEPARATORcSEPARATORdSEPARATOReSEPARATORf
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `join`, like:

```
   mystring = 'SEPARATOR'.join([var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d])
   print(mystring)
```

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
vars = [var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d]

res = 'SEPARATOR'.join(vars)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `join`:

If your variables are strings, you can simply do:

```
'SEPARATOR'.join([var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d])
```

If they aren't, you have to convert them to strings:

```
'SEPARATOR'.join(map(str, [var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d]))
```